# sum two values from different datasets using lookups in report builder

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report that should read values from 2 dataset by Currency:

```
Dataset1: Production Total
Dataset2: Net Total
```

Ive tried to use:

```vb
Lookup(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, 
       Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,
       Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, 
       "DataSet2")
```

This returns only the first amount from dataset 2.

I've tried Lookupset function as well but it didn't SUM the retrieved values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Jamie for the reply.
THis is what i have done and it worked perfect:
From Report Properties--> Code , write the below function:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0
For Each item As Object In items
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
Next
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

Then you can call the function:

```
code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

Comment: This works well.  But then how do you add a grand total to this?  I'm looking up amounts per project, but then want to total by customer...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Lookup will only return the first matching value. Three options come to mind:

1. Change your query, so that you only need to get one value: use a `GROUP BY` and `SUM(...)` to combine your two rows in the query. If you are using this query other places, then make a copy and change that.
2. Is there some difference in the rows? Such as one is for last year and one is for this year? If so, create an artificial lookup key and lookup the two values separately:

   ```
   =Lookup(Fields!Currency_Type.Value & ","
       & YEAR(DATEADD(DateInterval.Year,-1,today())), 
      Fields!Currency_Type1.Value & ","
       & Fields!Year.Value,
      Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, 
      "DataSet2")
   +
   Lookup(Fields!Currency_Type.Value & ","
      & YEAR(today()), 
     Fields!Currency_Type1.Value & ","
      & Fields!Year.Value,
     Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, 
     "DataSet2")
   ```
3. Use the [`LookupSet` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx) as mentioned.  With this you'll get a collection of the values back, and then need to add those together. The easiest way to do this is with embedded code in the report. Add this function to the report's code:

   ```
   Function AddList(ByVal items As Object()) As Double
      If items Is Nothing Then
        Return 0
      End If
      Dim Total as Double
      Total = 0
      For Each item As Object In items
         Total = Total + CDbl(item)
      Next

      Return Total
   End Function
   ```

   Now call that with:

   ```
   =Code.AddList(LookupSet(Fields!Currency_Type.Value, 
      Fields!Currency_Type1.Value,
      Fields!Gross_Premium_Amount.Value, 
      "DataSet2"))
   ```

(Note: this code was not tested. I just composed it in the Stack Overflow edit window & I'm no fan of VB. But it should give you a good idea of what to do.)